# Sticky Element on scroll issue on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ios9, sticky

This is for mobile only

I have a relative positioned element and when the scroll position is greater than the top position of the element, the element becomes fixed to the top of the screen.

In iOS, when scrolling the fixed element over-runs and appears to scroll off the screen until release.

This is my set up:

**CSS**

```
.sticky-element {
    position: relative;
}
.fixed-state {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
var orgStick = $('.sticky-element').position().top;
$(document).on("scroll", function(e) {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > orgStick) {
        $('.sticky-element').addClass("fixed-state");
    }
    else {
        $('.sticky-element').removeClass("fixed-state");
    }
});
```

I have tried adding transform3d to .fixed-state before I declare the position but this had no effect.
I have also tried using touchstart and scrollstart instead of scroll.
touchstart doesn't change anything whereas scrollstart completely stops the position from changing at all.

[Here is a jsFiddle simulating what I have done](https://jsfiddle.net/h2dwz6e7/)

How do I keep the element fixed to the top of the view port while scrolling on iOS?

What I have tried:

- -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch on the body and html but this had no effect.
- I have also tried using static but this fixes the element to the location it is within the html.
- I tried a work around where I had 2 elements, on is the fixed element and one is the relative element and just hid/shown the elements respectively. I still have the issue of the fixed element appearing to carry on scrolling until I release my finger.
- I have also tried using sticky instead of fixed, this stopped the element from sticking to the top of the view port
- I have also tried to use the plugins stickyjs and the jquery sticky-kit, These also presented the same issues.

Comment: Yeah, position: fixed seems to be very badly supported by iOS Safari. Does -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch work? I don't own an iPhone so I can't check.

Comment: Or position: static?

Comment: Static doesn't seem to keep the element at the top of the viewport, it just keeps the element in the location it is within the code.
I found here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp that static is not affected by the top property either.

Comment: I don't own an iPhone either, I use the emulator BrowserStack but that in itself can be buggy.

The -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch you mentioned is not a standard feature but I tried it and it did not make any difference. I applied it to the  body and the html in css.

Comment: I didn't get the iPhone emulator thing from BrowserStack working properly either. The whole class doesn't get added, nor does scrolling seems to matter. But maybe it was because I was using a Fiddle. It's not standard, but Safari is webkit based, so it should take. At my work we're using position fixed with the same zindex and all which seems to work, but it doesn't at your project. I really don't know why...

Comment: Hey, thanks Tom. I'm not sure sure what the problem is. I've successfully achieved this affect on other projects.

Will update if I find a solution

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a change to the way position:fixed is handled in iOS9+, apparently by design.

The simplest solution I've found it to prevent z-index transforms on child elements of the fixed element, e.g:

```
.is-sticky {

  > * {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me in Safari 13... Does it still work in your projects?